# middleware after all route in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I want to have a **middleware** like Express log request summary end of each route
=>

> [POST] /books/commentpart 200 1435.472 ms - 35

I want to log more data in end of each request. But I do not know how to write middleware like this. I have tried a middleware function after all route but it not worked. In each router, I also pass next() call.

---

```
app.use(responseTime());
//router
app

  .use(users(app, db))  
  .use(dataLogs(app, db))  
  .use(category(app, db));

//log middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next) {   
    var data = {};  
    var method = req.method;
    if(method == 'GET'){
      data = req.query;
    } else {
      data = req.body;
    }   
    var resTime = res.getHeader('X-Response-Time');    
    log.debug(' [ ' + iduser + ' ] - ' + req.route.path +  ' - ' + resTime + ' : ' + JSON.stringify(data));
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you share what you tried, but didn't work?

Comment: i have added more code, thanks

Comment: I think you should be able to implement something like that with [`morgan`](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan).

Answer (score 2):

So, middlewares, when registered (using `app.use`, `app.all`, or etc.) are a queue of rules that apply to incoming requests.  Note that this registration happens at the server-start time and is a part of the server itself, not requests.

Once it's all set up and the server is running, any hop (step in the queue, a.k.a middleware) after the first one is called only if the previous hop has called `next()` explicitly.  In other words, if you put a `app.use((req, res, next) => {});` at the beginning of all the middlewares, the server is gonna do absolutely nothing! -- this middleware is just swallowing any incoming request and not calling `next()`.

## Problem

Now the problem is, how can you register a middleware that:

1. **Applies to all rules, AND**
2. **Runs after all the other middlewares**

Satisfying the second requirement is not easy.  Because as we mentioned above the last hop in this rules queue runs only when all the previous ones have gracefully called `next()` one after another.  And sometimes it doesn't happen for various reasons, including simply forgetting to call `next()`!  And it's hard to enforce people to do that.

## Solution

I need to mention what @robertklep said in a comment above bolder. It's using `on-finished` on `res`! https://github.com/jshttp/on-finished

Example:

```
// have this before all the other middlewares
app.use((req, res) => {
    console.log("I'll be the first line executed, almost ever!");
    onFinished(res, (err) => {
        console.log("and I'll be the last one, knowing response"
                    + " code which is already sent is: " + res.statusCode);
    });
};
```

What this does is, actually listening on when the response is finished (you can alternatively use [on-headers](https://github.com/jshttp/on-headers)).  So it's a whole new dimension of doing a job on express, **prependicular to the existing middlewares queue mechanism.**  Just be careful and enjoy! ;)

Comment: dont forget to add ```next()```

Comment: @J.E.C. as a matter of fact, it's one of the rare middlewares that doesn't have `next()`!

Comment: if you add before all other middlewares, if you don't add ```next()``` the code will just hang - execution must be passed to the next middlewares

Answer (score 0):

middleware is just a function that do something and then pass the request to the next function using "next()". So if you really want to do that you need to catch all of your routes in the same route something like this

```
app.all('*', (req, res) => {
      // do something before

      // your async code here 

      // do something after
});
```

Comment: Middleware is only called "going in" (when the request is received), not "going out" (when the response is sent back), so if the logger depends on data that depends on the response (like a particular response header), you need to use something like [`on-headers`](https://github.com/jshttp/on-headers) or [`on-finished`](https://github.com/jshttp/on-finished).

Comment: Thats why what i demonstrate is that inside your controller you need to implement your logic as middleware then after that do something

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked. Actually, in some routes, i forgot pass next() in the end of each router.

Now i do another method, utilizing responseTime function and it works perfectly without add next() to all every routes. Thanks all!

```
app.use(responseTime(function (req, res, time) {
  var data = {};  
    var method = req.method;
    if(method == 'GET'){
      data = req.query;
    } else {
      data = req.body;
    }
   log.info(method, iduser, req.path, ' - ', Math.round(time), 'ms', ' : ', JSON.stringify(data));
}))
```

Comment: I think the reason `responseTime` has worked for you is because it's using `on-headers` internally: https://github.com/expressjs/response-time/blob/master/index.js#L55-L60

You can do the same and use `on-headers` or `on-finished` on their own.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `async / await`

```
const lastMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
    // Allow the route handler to run first and wait for it to be completed
    await next();

    // Do work
}
```